# Unable to open the gem file on textmate "bundle open gem_name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, textmate, bundler

I want to open the gem with textmate.

So I am using following commands:

```
export BUNDLER_EDITOR=mate
bundle open unicorn
```

Error:
Could not find gem 'unicorn' in the current bundle.

Note:

1)This commands used to work perfectly and it opened the whole gem with its contents, but suddenly some thing went wrong.

2) I am using rvm to manage my gems, & when i do :  $gemset list,  I do see the list of gems.

3) I also tried to automate the process by putting "export BUNDLER_EDITOR=mate" inside the ~/.profile  file inside my user folder.

4) When i do   ->  echo $EDITOR  ,  I dont get any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the similar problem. Although i am not a pro, but you should try to use another rvm gemset, Instructions are listed here http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/using/

Comment: "page not found"